# Restrict all non-ipsec traffic with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, ipsec

I'm using IPSEC in tunnel mode and I need to make sure that *all* traffic for a certain user on this computer is restricted to the VPN connection, and if the VPN is down the packets are rejected.

So effectively, all traffic is allowed unless the user is 'myuser'. If the owner is 'myuser' all non-ipsec packets (in and out) must be rejected.

I attempted this thinking that the first rule would catch all ipsec traffic and allow it, then block all non-ipsec traffic. However, this only blocked all traffic for myuser:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner myuser -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner myuser -j REJECT
```